Anylogic : how to stock an agent in a variable and compare it?
I am working on a model using links, and i wanted to stock in a variable an agent that is connected. This part works fine. Then, i want to use that variable to compare it to its value and use the result to send the agent to an output block.
The issue is that when i start the simulation, i see that the variable takes the value "4" when the agent is connected, but when i am comparing that variable of type agent with "4", i have this error : "Description: Cannot cast from int to Agent."
this is the function
here is the variable and the value it returns during the simulation

You cannot compare an Agent to a number. It is like comparing a car to a color. It does not make sense to Java :)
I assume you want to compare your Agent's variable position_assignee?
First, you need to use the actual agent type, let's say it is MyAgent. Then, you could compare in your function by providing an input argument myAgent of type MyAgent (not the capital letter!).
And in the function code, you can then use position_assignee == myAgent.position_assignee to compare the field of the agent who holds the function to the one you pass into the function.
(if this makes no sense, revisit some basic Java for AnyLogic)

I understand that the casting is not possible, the question that i'm asking is if it's possible to use the value of the variable ? because it will change a lot during the simulation and according to the value of the variable, some agents will go to a different block, and if i use "position_assignee == myAgent.position_assignee" it will always be true

not sure I follow, tbh. Maybe clarify in the original issue or open a new one. Try to create a simple example that illustrates your problem/question explicitly (this is how it works, this is what I want...)
